Is deinit called after a failable initializer returns nil in Swift?
If a failable class initializer in Swift returns nil, is deinit supposed to be called?
I can't find the answer in the documentation (e.g. https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/initialization), but searching for the question seems to bring up several discussions where the consensus is that deinit is not called (e.g. https://www.jessesquires.com/blog/2020/10/08/swift-deinit-is-not-called-for-failable-initializers/).
However, something like:
class Foo {
    init?() {
        return nil
    }
    
    deinit {
        print("You called?")
    }
}

Foo()

does print out "You called?" when I build & run it on Xcode 16.0. Is this undocumented/undefined behavior? Can I trust this to work in the future? Have I just missed the right documentation?

The behaviour seems to be that deinit is called if all the instance properties are initialised. If you put a var x: Int in there, for example, then the deinit will not be called.

I think not, but deinit of already initialized properties will be called 100%. So if you have some resource, that should be released, then create separate class just for it.

The documentation here describes the behaviour.

Similarly to convenience initializers, designated initializers can fail either before or after the super.init() delegation (or, for a root class initializer, the first location where all stored properties become initialized).
When failing after the super.init() delegation, we already have a fully-initialized self value, so releasing the self value is sufficient. The user-defined deinitializer, if any, is run in this case.
A failure prior to the super.init() delegation on the other hand will leave us with a partially-initialized self value that must be deallocated. We have to deinitialize any stored properties of self that we initialized, but we do not invoke the user-defined deinitializer method.

So whether or not deinit is run depends on whether all the stored properties of self have been initialised at the point of failure.
In your case, all the stored properties are initialised when init fails (vacuously true since there are no stored properties at all), so deinit is run. In many other cases, the stored properties are not fully initialised, and as the linked blog post says, it is not safe to call deinit in such cases.
For example, deinit will not be run for this class:
class C {
    var x: Int
    
    init?() {
        return nil
    }
    
    deinit {
        print("You called?")
    }
}

Implementation-wise, a return nil before all stored properties are initialised is compiled to a call to swift_deallocPartialClassInstance.

Thank you very much, especially for the relevant documentation link!
